# My media query is not working on windows becaus of the settings

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello I have an issue with my media query I added a media query of min-width:1920px in my code but it does not want to work I think that I know why but I can't solve it so I think it is because of in the settings in windows in display it is on 150% by default because when I put it on 100% it works so my question is does anyone know how to bypass this ?[image: here is the image of the settings]

So I tried to look for an anwser but it looks like I am the onlyone with this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No, you cannot bypass user display settings. You are not the only one with that issue. This is quite common. End users/visitors to your site won't really notice. I've had several clients with this exact issue - they can either change the setting or leave it as is.

Answer (score -1):

Could you add in your head, just after the :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can play with the scale value.
Let me know if that can change something, I'm not sure at all!:)

Comment: No it doesn't work but thanks for your answer